# Link a PHP file to an AJAX request in Magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I'm a newbie to Magento and I'm using Magento 1.9

I have a template file to a quick order form. As I need to add some custom php coding, I have created a php file under the same folder `(/templates/quickorder/QuickOrder.php)`.

What I need to implement is, when a user clicks on the **"Add to Cart"** button, an ajax request should be sent to my `QuickOrder.php` file and that will add the product to the cart.

So far my js code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button[name=addtocart]").click(function(){

        var id = $("select[name=product]").val();
        var qty = $("input[name=quantity]").val();
        $.ajax({
                url: 'QuickOrder.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: { 'pro_id': id,
                        'qty':qty 
                },
                success:function(data){

                },
        });

    });

});
```

And my `QuickOrder.php` file will accept the values and add the item to the cart.

```
$cart =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProduct($product, array('qty'=>$qty)); 
$cart->save();
```

This is not working. It cannot find the `QuickOrder.php` file.

My question is, can I specify the correct path to the php file without creating a separate module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new module with frontcontroller action 
for that you can refer this link
[magento New module action](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch)

Then you can give url of that action in your ajax code like

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://[hostname]/[magento]/frontname/index/action',
    .......
```